# How to change part of url (ID) using radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, radio-button

I got some radio buttons pushed by a loop in JSP:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="<s:property value="#country.getIdCountry()"/>">
```

The value of the radio button describe the ID of a country it selects.

Then I created some links eg.:

```
<a href='addDefaultPoints.action?countryId=<s:property value="#country.getIdCountry()"/>&height=400&width=350'>Link 1</a>           
<a href='editCountryMap.action?height=550&width=750&id=<s:property value="#country.getIdCountry()"/>&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true'>Link 2</a>
```

I would like to change code into some dynamic page, that can change the ID on the onChange event of the radio button set, within an url specified in href.

I tried using Javascript for this functionality, but with no luck. Perhaps I need to do this on the server side. I am using JSP, struts, Jquery and Javascript.

Here is what I tried:

```
var myGetValue = parseURL("id");
function checkV(f,v){
    for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        c[i].checked=(c[i].value==v)?true:false;
    }
}
checkV(myForm,myGetValue);
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Posted on the recent edit

Answer (score 1):

You can write below logic :

create url in hidden input with some constant name for county id, use same class name for corresponding anchor tag

```
<input class="COUNTY_ID" type="hidden" value="addDefaultPoints.action?countryId=COUNTY_ID&height=400&width=350">

<a class="COUNTY_ID" href="#"/>
```

write change event for radio button :

```
$('input[name="radioBtn"]').change(function(){

     var radioVal = $(this).val();
     var url = $('input[class="COUNTY_ID"]').val();

     url = url.replace('COUNTY_ID',radioVal);

     $('a[class="COUNTY_ID"]').attr('href',url);
});
```

Use similar logic for other links also ...

Comment: Thanks, I will check on that and let you know soon.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="2" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="4">

<a id="lnk1" href='addDefaultPoints.action?height=400&width=350&countryId='>Link 1</a>           
<a id="lnk2" href='editCountryMap.action?height=550&width=750&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&id='>Link 2</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var countryId = $('input[name=radioBtn]:checked').val();

    $('a#lnk1').attr('href', $('a#lnk1').attr('href') + countryId);
    $('a#lnk2').attr('href', $('a#lnk2').attr('href') + countryId);
});
```

**Explanation**

First you get the selected country by checking the **checked** radiobutton of the group **radioBtn**.
Then you make sure that the country param of your url is at the end so that you can concatenate the countryId to the rest of your links attribute 'href'.

**Result**

Link1:  `addDefaultPoints.action?height=400&width=350&countryId=2`

Link2:  `editCountryMap.action?height=550&width=750&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&id=2`

If the param is not ad the end of the link then you can use the `replace()` function like Bhushan Kawadkar mentioned.

Comment: This looks very nice, but the

    $('a#lnk1').attr('href', $('a#lnk1').attr('href') + countryId);

does not work as expected. The ID is not added at the end of the href for me. The ID is properly taken from radio buttons, but then ID's are not appended.